# Installing Dockerfile syntax highlighting not working in Atom Editor

Tags: atom-editor

I'm trying to install the `lanuage-docker` package (https://atom.io/packages/language-docker) using

```
apm install language-docker
```

However, after I restart atom my `Dockerfile` is still not syntax-highlighted:

[image]

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the lower right of Atom do you have the `Dockerfile` grammar (syntax) selected?

Alternatively the grammar switcher shortcut is: <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

[image: dockerfile grammar]